# Integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Tags: integration, analysis, substitution

I know that I should use substitution, but I am not really sure how.

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$$

Comment: The "how" is really all algebra.  What substitution did you have in mind?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Try to use the fact that $$\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1.$$

Comment: +1 I did not realise how good this answer was until the other two appeared after it!

Comment: An alternate choice: $\sec^2 \theta - 1=\tan^2\theta$.  Then you end up with $\int \sec\theta\;d\theta$ which you may already have done.

Answer (score 0):

There are really $12$ possibilities:
$$\begin{align}1-\sin^2\theta&=\cos^2\theta\\
1-\cos^2\theta&=\sin^2\theta\\
1+\tan^2\theta&=\sec^2\theta\\
\sec^2\theta-1&=\tan^2\theta\\
1+\cot^2&=\csc^2\theta\\
\csc^2\theta-1&=\cot^2\theta\\
\sinh^2\theta+1&=\cosh^2\theta\\
\cosh^2\theta-1&=\sinh^2\theta\\
1-\tanh^2\theta&=\text{sech}^2\theta\\
1-\text{sech}^2\theta&=\tanh^2\theta\\
\coth^2\theta-1&=\text{csch}^2\theta\\
1+\text{csch}^2\theta&=\coth^2\theta\end{align}$$
So of these, $4$ have the form $x^2-1$, so you could try them all.
$x=\sec\theta$, $dx=\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$ leads to
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\sec\theta\,d\theta=\ln|\tan\theta+\sec\theta|+C=\ln|\sqrt{x^2-1}+x|+C$$
Then if $x=\csc\theta$, $dx=-\csc\theta\cot\theta\,d\theta$,
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=-\int\csc\theta\,d\theta=-\ln|\csc\theta+\cot\theta|+C=-\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|+C$$
Or if $x=\cosh\theta$, then $dx=\sinh\theta\,d\theta$,
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int d\theta=\theta+C=\cosh^{-1}\theta+C=\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-1}|+C$$
And finally if $x=\coth\theta$m we have $dx=-\text{csch}^2\theta\,d\theta$,
$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=-\int\text{csch}\theta\,d\theta=-\ln|\text{csch}\theta+\coth\theta|+C=-\ln|\sqrt{x^1-1}+x|+C$$
The decreasing function substitutions have an extra minus sign, but consideration that the limits would be reversed by such a substitution will hopefully resolve that discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\arcosh}{arcosh}$

Assuming that the integrand is defined on the interval $(1, \infty)$ (rather than $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1, 1\}$), we can substitute for $x$ the function
$$
g(u) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
  (0, \infty) \to (1, \infty) \\
  u \mapsto \cosh(u)
\end{array}
\right.
$$
for which we have
$$
g'(u) = \sinh(u) \text{,}
$$
$$
g^{-1}(u) = \arcosh(u) \text{.}
$$
At this point you should convince yourself that we are indeed allowed to apply this substitution here!
Now using the hint given by Surb this yields
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}} dx
= \bigg[ \int \frac{\sinh(u)}{\sqrt{\cosh^2(u) - 1}} du \bigg]_{u = \arcosh(x)}
= \bigg[ \int \frac{\sinh(u)}{\sqrt{\sinh^2(u)}} du \bigg]_{u = \arcosh(x)}
=
$$
$$
= \bigg[ \int 1 du \bigg]_{u = \arcosh(x)}
= \bigg[ u + C \bigg]_{u = \arcosh(x)}
= \arcosh(x) + C \text{.}
$$